# Efficient algorithm for finding largest index j such that sum from index i to j is less than k

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm given an array of positive integers of size n. For every index i of the array, I want to find the largest index j such that the sum of the array elements from indices i to j is less than or equal to some integer K. I am able to think of only the brute force O(n^2) way. I was wondering if there is a more efficient approach?

Comment: Binary search of the range i through n-1 comes to mind, assuming the array is sorted. That would give you nlog(n), I believe.

Comment: Ah yes, as pointed by @Andrew Vershinin we would need to find the prefix sum and then binary search to give O(nlgn).

Comment: @gateway2745 Please see the corrected answer

Comment: nice!..technically the previous answer wasn't incorrect so maybe change the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer is incorrect, but I'll leave it, since it was accepted and has a comment.
There is a `O(n)` time, `O(1)` space sliding window (or, "two pointer") approach. The code below is in Java:

```
public static int[] rightBoundSums(int[] arr, long K) {
    final int N = arr.length;

    int[] ans = new int[N]; // the result

    int r = 0; // the right index of the window
    long sum = 0; // current sum
    for (int l = 0; l < N; l++) {
        // invariant: r is the first such index that 
        // sum(l, r - 1) > K, or N, if the end of the array was reached
        while (r < N && sum <= K) {
            sum += arr[r++];
        }

        if (arr[l] > K) {
            ans[l] = -1; // if the i-th element itself is larger, than K, there is no such j
        } else {
            ans[l] = (r == N) ? N - 1 : r - 2;
        }

        sum -= arr[l];
    }

    return ans;
}
```

---

Calculate prefix sums `pref[0] = 0, pref[i] = pref[i - 1] + arr[i - 1]`. Sums will be monotonically increasing, since values of `arr` are positive, so you can use binary search of the value `arr[i] + k` over prefix sums `pref[i + 1] ... pref[N]` for each `i` (mind the fact that prefix sums are 1-indexed). The resulting complexity will be `O(N logN)` time and `O(N)` space.

Comment: Upvoted this answer. Moreover, if the array is required to allow updates, it's possible to use a Fenwick tree, (which extends the prefix sum idea) [link](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/fenwick.html) ; [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree)